# A sub-domain for each user blog

Tags: nodes, uri

Is there any module, or a way to get a user blog in a separate sub-domain, such as user1.example.com for user1, and user2.example.com for user2?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a combination of blog module and [Subdomain](http://drupal.org/project/subdomain) module:

> Automatically creates subdomains and places content on them. There are
>   4 modes:
>
> User: e.g. "Mary" and content at http://mary.example.com
>
> Taxonomy: e.g. "Seattle" and content at http://seattle.example.com
>
> Organic Group: e.g. "MyGroup" and content at
>   http://mygroup.example.com
>
> Content type subdomains: e.g. "News" content at
>   http://news.example.com

Comment: This will not give sub-domain for each user blog.

Comment: Yes i try it and it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module might also be a good fit.
It can give you user based subdomains.